# How to extract specific string from the value column in dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to extract timestamp from the value column

i tried doing getItem however does not return anything

```
val data = df.withColumn("splitted", split($"value", "/"))
      .select($"splitted".getItem(6).alias("region"), $"splitted".getItem(7).alias("service"), col("value"))
      .withColumn("service_type", regexp_extract($"service", """.*(Inbound|Outbound|Outound).*""", 1))
      .withColumn("region_type", concat(
        when(col("region").isNotNull, col("region")).otherwise(lit("null")), lit(" "),
        when(col("service").isNotNull, col("service_type")).otherwise(lit("null"))))
      .withColumn("splitt", split($"value", "\t")
      .select($"splitt".getItem(1).alias("datetime"))
```

I need to extract timestamp with new column "datetime" 2019-05-14 04:02:03 from  below string;

```
{"value":"2019-05-14T09:02:06.486Z index:: host:: 2019-05-14 04:02:03,307 INFO  - \tTue May 14 04:02:03 CDT 2019\tID:<490744.1557824523305.0>\tsv\tAFTER_LOOKUP_QUERY_PARTNER_CHANNEL\t[messageData(DispatchID: 06708235871 Region: EMEA SubRegion: EU OperationType: <OperationType>STATUSUPDATE</OperationType> Operation: StatusUpdate)]\tms \t"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [regex_extract](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@regexp_extract(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,exp:String,groupIdx:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function to extract only timestamp from a string as below

```
df.withColumn("dateTime", 
      regexp_extract($"value", """\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\d [0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d""", 0)
).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+
|dateTime           |
+-------------------+
|2019-05-14 04:02:03|
+-------------------+
```

Comment: can you share your explanation please so i understand it better for my future reference